# Compilation failures in program?

Tags: java

I run it in JCreater but I keep getting compile errors. What did I do wrong? I saw someone set all the values to 0.0, but I don't see why I would need that.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class C2p3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double num1, num2, sum, difference, product; //setting variables

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter first number:");
        num1 = scan.nextDouble();   // not really sure what it does but I always use it and it works fine
        System.out.println("Enter second number:");
        num2 = scan.nextDouble();
        sum = num1 + num2;
        product = num1 * num2;
        difference = num1 - num2;
        System.out.println("Sum = " + sum);
        System.out.println("Product = " + product);
        System.out.println("Difference =" + difference);
    }
}
```

Comment: What compile errors exactly?

Comment: Please, for the love of god, use a propert IDE.

Comment: The first rule of asking for help is to be sure to provide useful information.  If you went to the doctor not feeling well, do you think you could get help if all you said was "I'm not feeling well"?  ALWAYS post the error message and/or complete stack trace.

Comment: The error message always is the key. Read it critically since it will show you *where* your problem is and usually *what* it is. If that fails, at least post it here!

Comment: It was it wouldnt compile on line 1, it said ; expected, and when I tried to run it, it said it couldnt find the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the Import statement carefully.

The statement

`import java.util*;`

should be

`import java.util.*;`

Extra info

If you really want to start writing good programs. I would suggest you make following changes to your code.

1. the statement `import java.util.*;` means that you are importing all the classes that are there inside the util package, But you are not using all of them in your code but the `Scanner` Class. So, I would suggest that replace the current import statement with `import java.util.Scanner;`.
2. Whenever you create an object of Scanner class. Call the method `scan.close()` when you dont need the object anymore. Else this might lead to resource leakage.
3. Please start using a proper IDE like eclipse, netbeans etc

Comment: @Sam I dint say JCreator is bad and I missed in your question that you are using JCreator. Use whichever IDE you prefer